# Listview item opening url of article

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, xml-parsing

I am trying to setup the onitemclicklistener to register which listview item was clicked and then grab the url for that article that is saved in the link and then opens a webpage with that url in a new activity.  Everything I try brings up errors that makes it not compile.  Currently the onitemclicklistener is throwing an error at `holder.articleLink.setText(currentItem.get("link"));` as well as down below where I declare the setText in the holder section at the very bottom.

```
public class L {
public static void m(String message)
{
    Log.d("test", message);
}
public static void s(Context context, String message)
{
    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ResultsCallback {

PlaceholderFragment taskFragment;
ListView articlesListView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        taskFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(taskFragment, "MyFragment").commit();
    } else {

        taskFragment = (PlaceholderFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyFragment");
    }
    taskFragment.startTask();

    articlesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.articlesListView);
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    BsuNewsTask downloadTask;
    ResultsCallback callback;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        callback = (ResultsCallback) activity;
        if(downloadTask != null) {
            downloadTask.onAttach(callback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public void startTask()
    {
        if(downloadTask != null) {
            downloadTask.cancel(true);
        } else {
            downloadTask = new BsuNewsTask(callback);
            downloadTask.execute();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        callback = null;
        if(downloadTask!=null) {
            downloadTask.onDetach();
        }
    }
}



public static class BsuNewsTask extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    ResultsCallback callback= null;

    public BsuNewsTask(ResultsCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public  void onAttach(ResultsCallback callback) {

        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public void onDetach() {

        callback = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onPreExecute();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String downloadURL="http://cms.bsu.edu/news/rss";
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            URL url=new URL(downloadURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            results = processXML(inputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            L.m(e + "");

        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> processXML(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory
                .newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDocument = documentBuilder.parse(inputStream);
        Element rootElement = xmlDocument.getDocumentElement();
        //print rootelement name in logcat
        //L.m("" + rootElement.getTagName());
        NodeList itemsList = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("item");
        NodeList itemChildren = null;
        Node currentItem = null;
        Node currentChild = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, String> currentMap = null;

        for(int i=0; i < itemsList.getLength(); i++) {
            currentItem = itemsList.item(i);
            itemChildren = currentItem.getChildNodes();

            currentMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (int j=0; j < itemChildren.getLength(); j++) {
                currentChild=itemChildren.item(j);
                if(currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                    //L.m(currentChild.getTextContent());
                    currentMap.put("title", currentChild.getTextContent());
                }
                if(currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                    //L.m(currentChild.getTextContent());
                    currentMap.put("description", currentChild.getTextContent());
                }
                if(currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                    //L.m(currentChild.getTextContent());
                    currentMap.put("link", currentChild.getTextContent());
                }
                if(currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")) {
                    //L.m(currentChild.getTextContent());
                    currentMap.put("pubDate", currentChild.getTextContent());
                }
            }
            if(currentMap != null && !currentMap.isEmpty()) {
                results.add(currentMap);
            }

        }
        return results;

    }
}


@Override
public void onPreExecute() {

}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results) {

    articlesListView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, results));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    MyAdapter adapter = (MyAdapter)l.getAdapter();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(adapter.dataSource.get(position).get("link"));
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}

interface ResultsCallback {
public void onPreExecute();

public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results);
}
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataSource = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataSource) {
    this.context=context;
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dataSource.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return dataSource.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    MyHolder holder = null;
    if(row == null){
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        holder = new MyHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (MyHolder) row.getTag();

    }
    HashMap<String, String> currentItem = dataSource.get(position);
    holder.articleTitleText.setText(currentItem.get("title"));
    holder.articleDescriptionText.setText(currentItem.get("description"));
    holder.articleDateText.setText(currentItem.get("pubDate"));
    return row;

}
}
class MyHolder
{
TextView articleTitleText;
TextView articleDescriptionText;
TextView articleDateText;

public MyHolder(View view) {
    articleTitleText=(TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.articleTitleText);
    articleDescriptionText = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.articleDescriptionText);
    articleDateText = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.articleDateText);


}
}
```

Comment: what is "L" in L.m(e + "");?

Comment: It is a class the tutorial used basically it calls the logcat using `public static void m(String message) {Log.d("test", message); } public static void s(Context context, String message)`

Comment: added the log class for those that had been asking

Comment: Why are you calling the setText method in a URL object? This melhod you use for TextView and EditText, for example.

Comment: It was just one of the many things I tried it crashes the program using that link so I have since removed it, it just happened to be the last one I did on my own before asking.

Comment: Ok. So please edit your question. And have you tried the answer below? And post your logcat with the current error.

Comment: I have tried the answer below when I put it in it gave me an error until I made the class abstract and iit wouldnt accept the paramaters for the ListItemClick I had to use the adapterview I made as code for it to be error free and compile then it gave the logcat file that is in the pastebin.  I will post the last working copy the onclick listener still doesnt work in it yet

Comment: Have you seen my comment in the anser: "You don't have to make the class abstract. As showed in the answer, you have to make your class implement the AdapterView.OnItemClickListener"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After compiling your code, I see you have to do some few modifications:

- set the item click listener in the `ListView`, this way:

  ```
  articlesListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
  ```
- After that, you have to make your activity implements the `OnItemClickListener`, this way:

  ```
  public class MainActivitySO extends ActionBarActivity implements ResultsCallback, 
  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
  ```
- Then, you will have to implement the method `onItemClick` in your activity. So, in this method you put waht the code you already have:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      MyAdapter adapter = (MyAdapter) articlesListView.getAdapter();
      Uri uri = Uri.parse(adapter.dataSource.get(position).get("link"));
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
      startActivity(intent);
  }
  ```

Comment: After adding      `articlesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.articlesListView);` with all this code, this compiled and loaded a the article in a webpage

Comment: You did not have it in the first implementation of your code?

Comment: Looking at how its compiled right now I have it 2x before and after the if/else statements adding it before worked yesterday

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the link from your dataSource:

```
public void onListItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    ListView l = (ListView) parent;
    MyAdapter adapter = (MyAdapter)l.getAdapter();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(adapter.dataSource.get(position).get("link"));
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

But first, implements the AdapterView.OnItemClickListener interface (sorry, I couldn't figure out how your onListItemClick method is called. If you already did this any other way, please ignore it)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ResultsCallback,AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     articlesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.articlesListView);
     articlesListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: I tried this code and in the public class MainActivity part it says Class 'MainActivity' must either be declared abstract or implment abstract method 'onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long)' in 'onItemClickListener'  also the this in the bottom one is saying adapterview cant be applied likely because of the implements error

Comment: I tried implementing this it wanted to make the class abstract so I did that and set a view.onclicklistener as well.  Then I had to change the listitemclick to `AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long l` to satisfy the errors and when I tried to run the program it just says it stopped and doesnt show the listview at all

Comment: Just got a bunch of logcat errors it was too long to paste them all I put it on pastebin.  http://pastebin.com/wA1a1QPF

Comment: You don't have to make the class abstract. As showed in the answer, you have make your class implement the AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.

Comment: You must not change the MainActivity to abstract. I will change the answer , maybe you will find it more simple...

Comment: Also, i made a mistake, the onListItemClick signature was wrong. try it again